# Angular4 with Polymer 1x, updated to polymer 2x, doesn't compile because of typescript errors

Tags: angular, typescript, polymer-2.x

I'm looking to update my Angular4/polymer 1.x project to polymer 2.0.  I'm using angular-cli to compile.  It won't compile because there are issues around typescript.

Anyone have a thought? [image]

Here is package.json

```js
{
  "name": "CredashboardClient",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-electron": "ng build --base-href . && copy src\\electron\\* dist",
    "electron": "npm run build-electron && electron dist"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.18",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "electron": "^1.7.9",
    "hammer-timejs": "^1.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsreport-browser-client-dist": "^1.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "pouchdb": "^5.4.5",
    "pouchdb-find": "^0.10.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.3",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.36",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.30",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.2.1",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

I made the changed suggested by AlesD, and that took care of much of it. I am left with this however,

`Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'customerElements'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `"skipLibCheck": true` in your `tsconfig.json` file. This way the typescript compiler does not run the checks you have enabled for the libraries.

From the TypeScript documentation: `skipLibCheck` boolean Skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts). [TypeScript compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: That took care of much of it but I am left with one error.  Cannot redeclare block-scoped vairable 'customElements'

Comment: Probably some other configuration is not ok also. Check what you have in the `"lib" : [ "es6, "dom", ...]` setting in the tsconfig.json. To me this looks like it tries to import the dom library twice for some reason. Try what happens if you remove it from lib.